# Layout errors when pinning UIView edges to UITableViewCell contentView

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Got a problem here which is driving me crazy.

In a storyboard I have a table view in a layout and I'm trying to pin the leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints of a UIView to the prototype cell's content view. Straightforward enough.

Whenever I do this I get these layout errors for the UIView in Xcode:

> "Need constraints for: X position, width"
>
> "Need constraints for : Y position, height"

[image: Problematic UIView]

[image: View hierarchy]

Constraints on that view (Superview is `contentView`):

[image: UIView constraints]

In the storyboard I have the following set on the table view:

- Row Height: automatic
- Estimate (row height): 50

[image: Table view settings]

And on the table view cell:

- Row Height: 50

[image: Table view cell settings]

I've seen a few SO posts and other walkthroughs that state that pinning the edges is what to do, and as I understand Auto Layout, I've provided the necessary constraints and info.

How can I fix this?

(BTW: I'm running Xcode 11.3.1.)

---

Update: The cells of this table view will be fixed height. I'm looking for the cell to provide the height for its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had the table view and cell constraints and settings configured properly; the problem was further up the view hierarchy.

The table view was placed in a vertical stack view, and that stack view's Alignment property was set to `center` (for the benefit of other views in the stack). This was causing issues for Auto Layout in calculating the *width* of the table view.

The solution here was to add an Equal Widths constraint from the table view to the stack view. *Et voila!* The errors on the UIView within the table view cell's content view disappeared.

[image: Fixer constraint]

Answer (score 2):

`UIView` by itself has no `intrinsicSize` - so you are telling the cell's contentView to pin to a frame of `0 x 0`.

If you are going to add content to the `UIView`, set the constraints on the content to control the size of the view and the errors will go away.

In the meantime, give the view a height constraint and that will resolve the issue.

---

**Edit**

For fixed-height cells... try starting fresh.

- Add a table view - give it desired constraints
- Add a table view cell prototype
- Add a `UIView` to that cell (give it a background color to make it easy to see)
- Constrain the view at Zero on all 4 sides (constrain to margins)
- Set the cell Row Height to 50 (un-check Automatic)

Here's how it looks for me:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm looking to have a fixed-height cell. In this case, how do I set up the table view so the cell provides the size to its content?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I thought doing this should be as simple, but it turns out my problem was further up the view hierarchy.